# Angular App crashes in production using conditional layout

Tags: angular

I have two layouts and each loads with condition:

```
<app-layout-w *ngIf="!p || p === 1">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-layout-w>

<app-layout-o *ngIf="p === 6">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-layout-o>
```

And the ts:

```
ngOnInit() {

 const subscription = this.authService.getToken().subscribe(token => {
  const payload = new NbAuthJWTToken(token.getValue(),
    token.getOwnerStrategyName(), token.getCreatedAt()).getPayload();
  if (payload) {
    this.p = payload.provider;
  }
 });

 this.userService.isAuthenticated.subscribe(isAuthenticate => {
    if (!isAuthenticate) {
      this.openDialog();
    }
 });

}
```

The error I have is:

> ERROR TypeError: "this.container is null"

The error is caused by `openDialog()`. What I noticed is that the layout is not loaded at all. I am using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

**Comment out the `openDialog()` avoids the error but a blank white page. No errors and nothing loading up.**

Comment: Could you share the code for the `openDialog` method. And what is `this.container`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.userService.isAuthenticated.subscribe(isAuthenticate = > {
    if (!isAuthenticate) {
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        this.openDialog();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I comment the `this.openDialog()` the error is gone but I see a blank page. Nothing loading.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in stackblitz ?